# Internet Protocol version 4 (IPv4) padding?

Tags: ipv4, ip, protocol-theory

Where is ip padding insert in ip data-gram format,
after payload?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only possible padding in an IPv4 packet would be in the header after any options. IPv4 options really are not used any longer, but if there are any options, the header must be padded to be sure that it ends on a 32-bit boundary. There is no payload padding because IPv4 simply doesn't care what is in the payload.

This is all explained in [*RFC 791, Internet Protocol*](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc791):

> 3.1.  Internet Header Format
>
> A summary of the contents of the internet header follows:
>
> ```
>  0                   1                   2                   3
>  0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1
> +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
> |Version|  IHL  |Type of Service|          Total Length         |
> +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
> |         Identification        |Flags|      Fragment Offset    |
> +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
> |  Time to Live |    Protocol   |         Header Checksum       |
> +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
> |                       Source Address                          |
> +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
> |                    Destination Address                        |
> +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
> |                    Options                    |    Padding    |
> +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
>
>                  Example Internet Datagram Header
> ```

-and-

> Padding: variable
>
> The internet header padding is used to ensure that the internet header
> ends on a 32 bit boundary.  The padding is zero.

-and-

> The options might not end on a 32-bit boundary. The internet header
> must be filled out with octets of zeros.  The first of these would be
> interpreted as the end-of-options option, and the remainder as
> internet header padding.

-and-

> Padding
>
> The internet header Padding field is used to ensure that the data
> begins on 32 bit word boundary. The padding is zero.

Comment: it is perfect answer